# Problema al reseteo contraseña laraval Class 'App\Notifications\UserResetPassword' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, login

Estoy intentando hacer la funcionalidad de contraseña olvidada pero me notifica el error que no encuentra una clase.

Estoy usando laravel 5.7
Tengo la clase importada pero me sigue saliendo el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo modelo **User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Notifications\UserResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new UserResetPassword($token));

    }
}
```

Este es el archivo **UserResetPassword.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class UserResetPassword extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {

        $mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        $mailMessage->view('Emails.Auth.Reminder', ['token' => $this->token]);

        return ($mailMessage)
            ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

ruta del archivo **UserResetPassword.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formulario **login.blade.php** donde esta el enlace que me lleva al otro formulario para restear la contraseña

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Inicio de sesion</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="login-formPanelImg">
                            <img class="login-formImg" src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}" />
                        </div>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                        value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Contraseña</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"
                                                {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Recordarme
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Inicio de sesion
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        Olvidaste tu contraseña?
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Este es el formulario **email.blade.php** donde se ingresa el correo para cambiar la contraseña

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Restablecer contraseña</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
        .abs-center {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Reset</title>

</head>

<body class="row-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8 abs-center">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header">Reestablecer Contraseña</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}" class="text-center">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-mail</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email"
                                        class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                        name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Send Password Reset Link') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

este es el archivo donde estan las rutas **web.php**

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sentResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard')->middleware('verified');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard')->middleware('verified');
```

Comment: ¿ya hiciste lo típico? Limpiar caché, du en composer, etc.

Comment: @Shaz Si compañero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En una parte estas mostrando el UserResetPassword.php del vendor por qué? No se supone que debe estar en app\notifications?

Osea la ruta de ese archivo como lo muestras en la consola debería ser c/xampp/ximple/app/Notifications

Estas agregando esa clase al vendor es una mala práctica, ya que al actualizar las versiones esos archivos se eliminan, en el vendor no se modifica nada.

la solucion es mover ese UserResetPassword.php para app\Notifications

Comment: Hol, si tienes razon pero ahora cuando recibo el ink para el reseteo me abre el una pagina en blanco.